# What exactly happens when you remove a task from recents?

Tags: android

I noticed a surprising behavior when removing an app from the app switcher by swiping. The app has a service. When the app is "killed", any threads started from the service keep running, other threads are terminated.

What's really surprising is that the system can determine which threads were started from the service, even if I try to obfuscate the thread's origin like this:

- In the service's onCreate() method, post a runnable to the main thread handler.
- The runnable starts a new thread which survives removal from recents.

If I post the exact same runnable to the exact same handler but from an activity, the thread doesn't survive. How can the system possibly know? Does it somehow track which thread was the runnable posted from?

Edit: As requested, the onCreate() method:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new Thread(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    while (true) {
                        System.out.println("hello from thread");
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }.start();
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Actually `Service`'s in android runs on `UI Thread` (unless you use `IntentService`)

Comment: and Android handlers contains `ThreadLocal` to check the UI Thread.

Comment: Kindly post your code for onCreate() if possible.

Comment: @PravinDivraniya  done

Comment: @MoshErsan that's the thing, the thread is *always* started from the UI thread but the system seems to know that it originated at the service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found out what happens. The system doesn't selectively kill non-service threads, it kills the whole app and then starts the service again, so it appears that the service's threads were untouched.

Comment: so if you have running process (ex. copying file) you will lose that file?

Comment: @MoshErsan I think the file will survive but it will just be incomplete.

Comment: that what i mean, so clearing app from recent will ruin your process

Comment: Yes, it will kill the process.

Answer (score 1):

Just want to throw some light on this.

Android components are oblivious to threads they did not create. So while *IntentService* will deal with the thread it created for the use of *onHandleIntent()*, a regular Service will pay no attention to any threads you fork yourself.

Once a service is destroyed, any threads it leaks will continue to run, until such time as Android terminates the process.

If your threads are stopping unexpectedly, that has nothing to do with *Service* -- again, *Service* knows nothing of threads that you fork yourself.

Comment: I'm aware of this of course, that's why the behavior was so confusing.

Answer (score 0):

From references,

it quits the app in the same way pressing back over and over again does. Sometimes, that kills its background processes as well, but sometimes it doesn't:

Removing an entry in recent tasks will kill any background processes that exist for the process. It won’t directly causes services to stop, however there is an API for them to find out the task was removed to decide if they want this to mean they should stop. This is so that removing, say, the recent task of an e-mail app won’t cause it to stop checking for e-mail.

If you really want to completely stop an app, you can long press on recent tasks to go to app info, and hit force stop there. Force stop is a complete kill of the app—all processes are killed, all services stopped, all notifications removed, all alarms removed, etc. The app is not allowed to launch again until explicitly requested.

So basically, it's up for the app to decide, and depends on how the app was coded. It's worth watching the screen in Settings > Apps > Running to see how each app acts

Please check below refrence link for more info.

Refrence Links:-

http://lifehacker.com/what-happens-when-you-remove-an-app-from-androids-mult-1179868228

http://www.howtogeek.com/169549/what-exactly-happens-when-you-swipe-an-android-app-from-the-recent-apps-list/

https://plus.google.com/+DianneHackborn/posts/GfwRYCC42uX